# Long font and flat font

Tags: css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LDCT.jpg

In the above link (image), style of text on left side is different from that on right side.Left side text is thin and other is round. What css should I apply to make this change?

Our designer said both fonts are Arial Narrow.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't written any code. I don't know what css style to apply

Comment: do you want all this css code? that means exact design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

use

```
letter-spacing: 1px;  // your required value
word-spacing: 1px; // your required value
```

and set the same `famil-style` and same `family-font`.